# Element-wise addition of two lists of different lengths?

Tags: python

How to perform element-wise addition of different length lists?
Assuming "0" for missing elements.
Note: len(a) will always be less than or equal to len(b)

example:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Desired result:

```
result=[2,4,6,4,5]
```

I can almost, but not quite do this with:

```
result=[sum(n) for n in zip(a,b)]
```

Is it possible to automatically append '0' elements to (list a) so it is the same length as (list b), prior to doing the zip? If that is a good pythonic solution, how would one do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an alternative `zip` that does not stop at the shortest: [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest). You can specify a fill value for the shorter lists:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

result = [sum(n) for n in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `izip_longest`:

```
>>> izip_longest(a,b,fillvalue=0)
<itertools.izip_longest object at 0x10bbd2520>
>>> list(_)
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5)]
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> [sum(t) for t in izip_longest(a,b,fillvalue=0)]
[2, 4, 6, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to import anything, you can just append a number of zeroes at the end of the shorter list.

```
result = [sum(n) for n in zip(a + [0] * (len(b) - len(a)), b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pad a with zeroes like this and use sum

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3,4,5]
a[:] = [a[i] if i < len(a) else 0 for i,j in enumerate(b)]
result=[sum(n) for n in zip(a,b)]
print result
```

results in

```
[2, 4, 6, 4, 5]
```